# Macbook Pro keyboard does not work on startup

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos

I'm having this issue since morning. Certain keys on my keyboard don't work when I try to type in my password. A few work and others don't. So I went on safe mode and changed it to no password.

The problem is that my keyboard works perfectly once I've logged into my MacBook Pro. I can type this entire paragraph properly but only only the login screen my keys don't work.

What is wrong with my MacBook Pro?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?   And have you tried resetting the PRAM and/or SMC?

Answer (score 3):

I would reset both the System Management Controller and PRAM/NVRAM.

**Reset the SMC**

Instructions for resetting your System Management Controller (SMC) will depend on whether your MacBook Pro runs from a built-in battery or a removable battery.

As your question doesn't provide the exact model, use the relevant instructions below:

**SMC 1 - For MacBook Pros, MacBook Airs, and MacBooks where you can’t remove the battery on your own (i.e. it's a built-in battery), here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

**SMC 2 - For MacBook Pros, MacBooks etc that you can remove the battery from, here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. **Disconnect** the MagSafe plug (power cable) from the computer
3. Remove the battery
4. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> for 5 seconds and release
5. Put the battery back in
6. Reconnect the MagSafe cord (or power cable)
7. Turn your computer back on with the power button

**Reset your PRAM/NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). It may be worth you also resetting this. Here’s how to:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

Give these a go and let us know how you go.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue, which seemed to occur due to a video game I would have running when I shut the laptop. Because it (the video game) was in fullscreen mode, apparently the cursor and keyboard input were still functioning through the game rather than the login screen.

Pressing <kbd>Cmd-Tab</kbd> to cycle windows changed my keyboard/mouse over to the login screen. Even though it wasn't actually visibly changing screens, the cursor would disappear and reappear each time I pressed those keys.